# YAML (Ruby) loading "on" as true

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am trying to load a list of words from a YAML file. In the file there is an entry

```
- on
```

Ruby is loading this as "true", instead of "on". Similarly "off" is loaded as "false".  A quick check on the Psych code shows "yes" and "no" are treated the same way.

Is there any way I can change this behaviour, other than adding quotes around on and off?

I am able to see the values if I read the file and parse, instead of load_file.

```
# test.yaml
- true
- false
- yes
- no
- on
- off
- y
- n
- Y
- N
```

I get a Psych document by parsing instead of loading, which has the text before transformation to native.

```
YAML.parse_file('test.yaml')
```

Wondering how to extract it correctly.

From the docs

"The representation stage means data which has been composed into YAML::BaseNode objects. In this stage, the document is available as a tree of node objects. You can perform YPath queries and transformations at this level. (See YAML::parse.)"

Require help on writing a comprehensive YPath query to extract data.

(PS: This may seem a bit roundabout, but that cleans up a lot of things in data management for me)

Comment: Do you have privileges to edit the `yaml` file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already explained in other answers, `on` is considered a "truthy" value. This behavior is [intentionally coded in Psych](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/7e7ccf6fa4ee084c673d5a52888e2e18a41bfb5b/test/psych/test_boolean.rb#L8).

The best solution to the problem, as explained by Arup Rakshit and Mikhail P, is to quote the value. However, given that your question asks for an alternative, here's an alternative.

Scalar conversion in Psych is hard-coded in [`Psych::ScalarScanner#tokenize`](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/ad86a7474d61fcdce25e6aceec3e29bec3dd919f/lib/psych/scalar_scanner.rb#L52-L55). A possible (but strongly discouraged) option is to monkey patch this method to change this `case statement`

```
    when /^(yes|true|on)$/i
      true
    when /^(no|false|off)$/i
      false
```

As you probably realize looking at the source code, the method is quite long and the monkey patch will force you to copy/paste a quite big chunk of code. There's no easy way, the options are hard-coded into the select case (one more sign that this is not a good idea).

Personally, I would never go that way. Modifying the core behavior of Psych may lead to several unexpected side effects, since other libraries may depend on this behavior.

---

Another option, if you don't want to modify the original file physically, is to write a proxy that changes it at runtime.

In practice, you can create a CustomYaml parser, that implements a `parse_file` method. The method will read the content of the file in memory, perform a "search & replace" of any occurrence of unescaped `on` into `"on"`, then feel `YAML.load()`.

This will cheat the `YAML` parsing, causing it to interpret each "on" token as scalar string.

Similar to this pre-processing approach, you can adopt a post-processing approach by traversing the YAML AST returned by Psych.

Comment: Doing a pre-processing is an option. Thanks!

Comment: Psych left out "Y" and "N" if the YAML reference card (see Mikhail P's post) is the basis.

Answer (score 5):

It's listed on the YAML [reference card](http://www.yaml.org/refcard.html), though I can't find any reference to it in the spec.

```
Language Independent Scalar types:
   ...
    { Y, true, Yes, ON  }    : Boolean true
    { n, FALSE, No, off }    : Boolean false
   ...
```

I think quotes are your only option.

Comment: Interesting! Y and n are not implemented in Psych as boolean.

Comment: FYI, the yes/no aliases for true/false were removed in the YAML 1.2 spec (the current one). That's probably why you don't see it. It was in YAML 1.1, and I guess some packages are still supporting 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Just made it work by modifying the AST as you hinted.

The code is as follows:

```
src = YAML.parse(data)
src.select{ |node| node.is_a?(Psych::Nodes::Scalar) &&
                   %w(on off).include?(node.value) }
  .each{|node| node.quoted = true }
```

So basically, this just tricks the system into thinking that all the value nodes with values `on` and `off` are quoted. That makes them look as strings.

Of course, this is implementation-dependent, for others than Psych this will have to be done differently.

Comment: I guess i have got  simpler version now, just for my current requirement. However, in a more generic case, we might have to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for my current requirement.

```
require 'yaml'

ydoc = YAML.parse_file('test.yaml')
puts ydoc.children.map { |sequence| sequence.children.map { |scalar| scalar.value }}
```

The "children" helps to move down from Psych Document > Psych Sequence > Psych Scalar.

Please let me know your comments.